# When sending email to Gmail address from netcat or openssl s_client, why do I get "Username and Password not accepted", despite correct credentials

Tags: email, openssl, netcat

My goal was to send an email to a gmail address, like `beta@gmail.com` from a commandline tool such as netcat or telnet etc.

***WHAT I TRIED:***

I first tried netcat.

```
nc -C smtp.gmail.com 587
220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP l35sm2846203wms.40 - gsmtp
EHLO smtp.gmail.com
250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [101.50.65.95]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8

MAIL FROM:alpha@gmail.com

530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. l35sm2846203wms.40 - gsmtp

STARTTLS
220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS

MAIL FROM:alpha@gmail.com
```

Then the **session would close automatically.** In the above snippet, `alpha@gmail.com` is **my real Gmail email address** (ofcourse changed to `alpha` for online posting). When I did some web search about the matter, I found that everyone was saying that **`netcat`** or **`telnet`** could not be used, and instead **`openssl s_client`** were to be used.

Then I started following [a tutorial](https://taufanlubis.wordpress.com/2016/02/08/how-to-send-email-via-gmail-server-using-openssl/) to use `openssl s_client` to do that. And this happens, even though the username and password are correct, and I can login from web browser.

```
openssl s_client -connect smtp.gmail.com:465 -crlf 
CONNECTED(00000003)
...
    Start Time: 1630494318
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: no
    Max Early Data: 0
---
read R BLOCK
220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP z137sm5722297wmc.14 - gsmtp
ehlo smtp.gmail.com
250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [101.50.65.95]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
auth login
334 VXNlcm5hbWU6 #########################################ASKING FOR BASE64 ENCODED USERNAME. I ENTER MY REAL (BASE64 ENCODED) GMAIL EMAIL ADDRESS alpha@gmail.com HERE. 
******************************
334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6 #########################################ASKING FOR BASE64 ENCODED PASSWORD. I ENTER (BASE64 ENCODED) PASSWORD OF MY GMAIL EMAIL GIVEN ABOVE. 
*****************
535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials z137sm5722297wmc.14 - gsmtp
```

***QUESTION:***
Why is this happening, and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: This is not really a security question. Also, make sure to check the link mentioned in the response of the mail server and follow all the steps, including the one with the captcha.

Comment: To start with, Google considers all non-Google clients as insecure. You need to go into your Google account and set it to allow insecure clients.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```shell
openssl s_client -ign_eof  -connect smtp.gmail.com:465 -crlf
```

The `-ign_eof` command line argument helps.